# Short scifi story about a painter with artificial eyes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, art

The details are hazy, but as far as I can remember there is an artist that was either blind or had poor eyesight and underwent surgery and after receiving artifical eyes could create paintings that had information in the invisible part of the spectrum which caused people to react to the paintings wildly. Not sure about the specific details.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Where?  (Was it in an anthology, a magazine or online?)

Comment: It was a while ago in a anthology magazine so it has to be an older one or a "classic" story. Definitely older than 15 years and likely more than that.

Comment: Sounds like some Zelazny story, but I am not so sure which one

Comment: Still trying to figure this one out. Haven't managed to track it down yet. I went through some Zelazny stories but couldn't find it.